# Community Ads to use in other sites

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I just noticed your site and I'm happy you guys made it into beta; I wish you all the best in making this a great site.

One nice way to let the world know about this site is via the Community Ads which are available on fully-grown Stack Exchange sites. There are a bunch of related SE sites and these ads are a potential resource for you guys to find users; for an example see [this year's thread in Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/community-promotion-ads-2015). I've gone ahead and created [this image](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6505/8563) for the Physics site,

[image: Engineering Stack Exchange]

<sup>[Inkscape SVG source](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g9ukpl8blkv8qi5/EngineeringAd.svg?dl=0)</sup>

but if you guys can come up with something more compelling I'm pretty sure we'll be happy to host it over there. You can then post these in other SE sites and essentially ask their communities to advertise you. If you come up with good material, it can also become a good starting point for your site's graphical identity.

Just something to think about.

---

#### Update

So the Community Ads threads have been changed slightly this year to accommodate a change in the width of the sidebar. To match this, here is a new image to the new specifications:

[image: Engineering Stack Exchange]

with its corresponding [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/engineering%20ad%202016.svg). This runs at double the standard size to provide better resolution for [retina display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_Display) users, whatever that actually is. This one is currently in proposed status [on the 2016 Physics thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7443/8563).

Comment: Nice job putting the ad together.  Thank you!  I think the image is fine enough, as is, for a community promo ad.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7169/53019

Comment: Posted on [mathematics](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/community-promotion-ads-2015/19595#19595). Thanks, E.P, for the ad.

Comment: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5123/34665

Comment: Any chance to add some color to the image

Comment: @Mahendra you're welcome to create your own version. Post it as a separate answer so there's more variety.

Answer (score 2):

This will be a community wiki answer to track the progress of the ads. As a reminder: A post on a site's Community Ads page needs 6 upvotes for the ad to be shown on that site. Each of our posts on those sites will be tracked here, with the score periodically updated. Don't forget - we can add more ads on other sites (that aren't in beta)!

[Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/community-promotion-ads-2015/5123#5123) - 3

[Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/community-promotion-ads-2015/19595#19595) - 3

[Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/community-promotion-ads-2015/6505#6505) - 10

[Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7070/community-promotion-ads-2015/7169#7169) - 6